# SQL- Change column value based on other column values in same group & different row

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server:

[image: Table with Unique IDs that can be part of the same Group]

Unique `ITEM_ID` are part of a group (`GROUP_NUMBER`). `IS_ACTIVE` and `IS_LAST` are either 1 - true , or 0 - false.

**What I want to do:**

I want to go through this table and for every active `ITEM_ID` (`IS_ACTIVE = 1`) that is the ONLY active `ITEM_ID` in it's group (`GROUP_NUMBER`) I want to make that row's `IS_LAST` is set to 1.

So for example, in the table above, the row for `ITEM_ID = 6`, I want `IS_LAST` to be  1

I am not sure how to do this as I am not that versed in SQL. I am trying to use a `partition by` command to maybe split each group up but doing the check to see if an `ITEM_ID` is the only active in its group seems challenging.

Any help or guidance here is appreciated.

It should be noted that I do not want to do an update or change the actual table in any way, just design a query that can do the changing and spit out an altered version of that table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is solution:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(ITEM_ID INT, GROUP_NUMBER INT, IS_ACTIVE BIT, IS_LAST bit)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 0),
(2, 1, 1, 0),
(3, 2, 0, 0),
(4, 2, 0, 0),
(5, 2, 0, 0),
(6, 3, 1, 0),
(7, 3, 0, 0)


SELECT t1.ITEM_ID, 
       t1.GROUP_NUMBER, 
       t1.IS_ACTIVE, 
       CASE WHEN t1.IS_ACTIVE = 1 AND 
                   NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @t t2 
                              WHERE t2.IS_ACTIVE = 1 AND t1.GROUP_NUMBER = t2.GROUP_NUMBER AND 
                                       t1.ITEM_ID <> t2.ITEM_ID) 
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IS_LAST 
FROM @t t1
```

Answer (score 2):

The following query returns the `ITEM_ID`'s where only one is active in the group:

```
select ITEM_ID from MyTable M 
where IS_ACTIVE = 1 and 
  not exists (select null 
              from MyTable N where n.IS_ACTIVE = 1 and 
                M.GROUP_NUMBER = N.GROUP_NUMBER and M.ITEM_ID <> N.ITEM_ID)
```

You can then `left join` this query with `MyTable`. Something like:

```
select *
from MyTable A left join (<query above>) B on A.ITEM_ID = B.ITEM_ID
```

If B.ITEM_ID is not Null then IS_LAST = 1.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right tracks with Partition By. The best way I can think to do this is with some code like:

```
SELECT Item_ID, Group_Number, Is_Active, 
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Group_Number, Is_Active ORDER BY Group_Number) [Members_In_Set], 
CASE WHEN Is_Active = 1 AND COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Group_Number, Is_Active ORDER BY Group_Number) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [Is_Last]
FROM My_Table
```

The Members_In_Set column is to demonstrate what the count returns when partitioning and then the CASE shows how to use this value along with Is_Active to get the result you're after